# Running a function in a print command returns None Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am writing my first program that I intend to use for managing a winery warehouse. The program is supposed to show in which location what pallet is located and other info about it.

My issue is that it looks messy so I wrote a simple function to print lines in order to line up all the numbers. However, whenever i call the `lines` function inside the print command, it returns a `NoneType Error`.

I tried running the `lines` function separately and it work fine, it just messes up when it's in the `print` function.

```
print('pallet program')
warehouse={'a1':{'location':'A1','name':'Gran cuvee','year':'2016','amountbottle':'600','amountboxes':'40'},
           'a2':{'location':'A2','name':'Merlot','year':'2017','amountbottle':'400','amountboxes':'60'},
           'a3':{'location':'A3','name':'Vranec','year':'2016','amountbottle':'100','amountboxes':'30'},
           'a4':{'location':'A4','name':'Cabarnet sauvignon','year':'2019','amountbottle':'900','amountboxes':'10'}
           }
def lines(a):
    print('-'*(10-len(a)))

print('Pallet 1:\nLocation:'+warehouse['a1']['location']+
      '\nName of wine:'+warehouse['a1']['name']+
      '\nYear:'+warehouse['a1']['year']+
      '\nAmount:\n   Bottles:'+warehouse['a1']['amountbottle']+'\n   Boxes:'+lines(warehouse['a1']['amountboxes'])+warehouse['a1']['amountboxes'])
```

Is there something I am missing? I don't want a return function as it would change the value inside the dictionary. Or so I think. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `lines()` in the `print()` function, print tries to print whatever your function returns. Since it does not return anything, you get the error. It works, if you define the function to return a string:

```
def lines(a):
    return ('-'*(10-len(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`lines()` does not return a string, so you can't print it. Try this:

```py
def lines(a):
    return '-' * (10 - len(a))
```